# Paste RTF as formatted Markdown; export markdown as formatted HTML

Tags: linux, markdown, rtf

I currently use Ulysses to paste RTF formatted text from Powerpoint as formatted Markdown text. This is done using the "Paste From" option under the edit menu.

I then use the export feature of Ulysses to paste formatted HTML to the clip board. I can then past the HTML formatted code into a database.

I'm moving from a Mac environment to a Linux environment. Ulysses isn't available on Linux. I can't find any Markdown editor on Linux that allows these two operations.

Has anyone else run into this issue? Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround. Dropbox's "PAPER" will allow you to paste in RTF. It will also allow you to export a markdown file. Open that file in GHOSTWRITER. You can now copy the HTML to your clipboard.